# How can i pick a folder that have another file not only .jpg

Tags: jython, jes

I have to pick a folder that has another file that is not only .jpg. 
How can I change it?

```
import os

def titleDirectory(dir):
  for file in os.listdir(dir):
    print "Processing:",dir+"//"+file
    picture = makePicture(dir+"//"+file)
    addText(picture,10,10,"This is from My CS Class")
    writePictureTo(picture,dir+"//"+"titled-"+file)
```

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEhNm.jpg)

Comment: import os 

def title(dir):
  for file in os.listdir(dir):
   if dir+file+".jpg":
    print "Processing:",dir+"//"+file
    picture = makePicture(dir+"//"+file)
    addText(picture,10,10,"This is from my cs class")
    writePictureTo(picture,dir+"//"+"titled-"+file)

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, [edit] your question and paste the code as text. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.